# alert and confirm boxes do not appear

Tags: javascript, php, xhtml

I have a couple of webpages which i in part build up dynamically (php and JavaScript).

Everything used to work well in the past, but now the various calls to `alert` and `confirm` do not cause dialog boxes to appear anymore.

Using the JavaScript debugger in firefox i can verify, for example, that the statement

```
var r = confirm("Do you really want to save this data?");
```

is executed, but no dialog window is opened, and the code goes on as if i had pressed "no" (in this step the watch expression for r changes from "undefined" to "false").

The same happens for calls to `alert` - the code is executed, but no dialog window is shown.

I have not checked these pages in a while, which means there have been various software updates since then.

Strangely however, this seems not to be a browser-wide effect: a different set of similarly built pages does not show this behavior - there, the dialog boxes are shown.

Is it possible that there is some setting in JavaScript or php which prevents dialogs from opening?

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console of your browser? Are you using those alerts/confirms in a(n) (i)frame?

Comment: There are  no errors n the console and i don't use any frames or iframes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and my problem was solved with the following code. You try it too, maybe it will help you too.

```
let r = window.confirm("Do you really want to save this data?");
```

Comment: i tried with ```let r = ...``` but still no dialog boxes are shown

Comment: add window before confirm it means call confirm method from window object like this window.confirm

Comment: I also tried ```let r = window.confirm("Do you really want to save this data?");``` but still no visible dialog boxes